# Simple form submit with python

Tags: python

I am totall newbie to python so if the question will be totally newbie please excuse me.
I have simple landing page `index.html` and have a form there:

```
<form action="getPhone.py" method = "POST">
First name:
<input type="text" name="firstname" >

Phone:
<input type="text" name="lastname" >

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

So can you provide a simple basic example of `getPhone.py` for me How to get data from this form ( I want to send this data via email, but as first step i just have to get it) ?
`UPD`: I am developing on windows.I don't know about such things as will my server be able to execute cgi scripts or not.

Comment: Can your webserver execute [Python CGI scripts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html)?

Comment: i don't really know=) I am totall newbie as I stated before.If it is necessary I can make my webserver execute cgi scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your web-server doesn't support Python CGI scripts, you could use some micro-framework.
For example, using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/):

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/get_phone/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_phone():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print 'First name:', request.form['firstname']
        print 'Phone:', request.form['lastname']

    return 'Take a look at your terminal!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

(Please note that you use a textbox named `"lastname"`, but you call it `"Phone"`. I did the same.)

Then run it and use `http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_phone/` instead of `getPhone.py`:

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_phone/" method="POST">
```

It's a more popular way, especially if you consider growing your site. If you won't need anything else, you could go with CGI and python-supported web-server.

Actually, it would make sense if you provide some more information on what you're trying to do. Do you want to create your own website and have no idea on how it works? I guess it'd be easier for you to jump right into the web-frameworks like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Django](http://djangoproject.com/).

If you aren't sure you'd like to progress in web-development and just want to learn Python and its builtin libs, you can set up some webserver or take a look at [Python's webservers manual](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html).

Comment: if you do go down the road of using flask - this is a fantastic tutorial - http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Comment: The answer to your question about progressing in web development with python - right now I just have to build simple landing page which is needed only for collecting names and phone number.So that's why I don't want to use something like django. I just need things to work with as less actions from me as available.If I like the result later I will consider to use python  for bigger projects of course=)

Comment: i just heard that python web development is easy and interesting so now trying it=)

Comment: I did as stated  in your answer but when I  submit my form I get the following : `page: http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_phone/` is not available

Comment: @user2950593 Have you left that python file (the one with `app.run()` at the end) running? What does it say? There's a [quickstart manual](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#quickstart) for Flask, you can check if everything's alright. You should get the "`Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/`" message after you run it. Then the said page should be available. :)

Comment: I managed to repair. firstly I didn't install flask and I changed your code a little bit cause differences in python versions. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327658/simple-form-submit-python

Comment: can you please update the answer with improvements from the link in the last comment for the future users?