# Simple form submit python

Tags: python, flask

I have simple python app which gets name and phone from html form submit using post method.
I have this in my index.html:

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_phone/" method = "POST">
First name:
<input type="text" name="firstname" >

Phone:
<input type="text" name="lastname" >

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And have my `getPhone.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/get_phone/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_phone():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print ('First name:', request.form['firstname'])
        print ('Phone:', request.form['lastname'])

    return 'Take a look at your terminal!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

But when I submit my form with  I get the following message in my browser:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in
>   the application.

In my console I have this:

```
>  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2015 22:20:04] "GET /get_phone/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2015 22:20:12] "POST /get_phone/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2015 22:26:22] "GET /get_phone/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

How to fix this?

UPD: consoleLog with debug = true:

```
     * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2015 22:35:30] "POST /get_phone/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_except
ion
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch
_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_e
xception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch
_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_requ
est
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\nevernight\Desktop\visa + py\getPhone.py", line 6, in get_phone

    if request.method == 'POST':
NameError: name 'request' is not defined
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2015 22:35:32] "GET /get_phone/?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resou
rce&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2015 22:35:32] "GET /get_phone/?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resou
rce&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2015 22:35:33] "GET /get_phone/?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resou
rce&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2015 22:35:34] "GET /get_phone/?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resou
rce&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2015 22:35:34] "GET /get_phone/?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resou
rce&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2015 22:35:34] "GET /get_phone/?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resou
rce&f=source.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2015 22:35:35] "GET /get_phone/?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resou
rce&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Replace `app.run()` with `app.run(debug=True)` to get more information about what is going wrong. Though it seems the issue is that you haven't imported `request`.

Comment: to clarify your likely issue that @Sevanteri referenced `from flask import Flask,request`

Comment: thanks  it works=)  import request i mean, can any of you write it as an answer so I can accept it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you haven't imported `request`.
Like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
```

Answer (score 0):

All variables that you put in a route you have to make sure that they are imported at the top of your flask route page.